# Can't solve this error: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, sql, parameters, compiler-errors, insert

I'm getting this invalid parameter number error, even though I have exactly two bound variables and two tokens, I only need to insert those two values so I entered the rest of the columns as null. Here it is

```
connecting::query('INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (null,null,null,\'0\',null,null,:something,null,null,null,null,null,null:somethingElse,null,null)', array(':social'=>$social,':noise'=>$noise));
```

Here's the method being called:

```
public static function query($query,$params = array())
    {


        $statement = self :: db()->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute($params);
        if(explode(' ',$query)[0] == 'SELECT')
        {
            $data = $statement->fetchAll();
            return $data;
        }

    }
```

Comment: there's a `,` missing before `:somethingElse`. And you are binding to `:social` and `:noise`, but have the tokens "something" and "somethingElse"

Comment: wow thanks man can't believe I missed that